# MyPy error from using subclass variables in metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, metaclass

I have to use a metaclass and need to access a subclass variable inside the new function (so it's essentially an abstract property). This gives MyPy errors of course, because 'type' has no attributes named FILE_PATH nor ADDRESS. Is there any workaround here?

```
class metaClass(type):

  def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
      x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

      if not hasattr(x, "FILE_PATH") or not hasattr(x, "ADDRESS"):
          raise NotImplementedError("FILE_PATH and ADDRESS not set")

      #do stuff with x.FILE_PATH and x.ADDRESS
      path = x.FILE_PATH  #  <- "mypy --strict" errors here
      ...
      return x

class subClass(metaclass=metaClass):
    FILE_PATH = "file.type"
    ADDRESS = "sadfsadfa"
```

**UPDATE:**

Solved by using `dct['FILE_PATH']` and `dct['ADDRESS']` to access the variables set in the child class.

Comment: Does setting `x.FILE_PATH` and `x.ADDRESS` to dummy values before raising the exception make `mypy` happy?

Comment: (I can't seem to reproduce the issue, though.)

Comment: Also, `subClass` isn't actually a subclass, or rather, it's only a subclass of `object`, like any other class without an explicit parent class.

Comment: Setting dummy values suppresses warnings in PyCharm, but MyPy is still unhappy with it.

Comment: Can you provide an exact recipe that produces the problem (including how you invoke `mypy`, with any necessary options)?

Comment: @chepner: there, I added it. MyPy flags it when one actually tries to retrieve the attribute. (when run as  `mypy --strict`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if the attributes are on the created class `dct` as in the workaround you have found have one big drawback - which might or not apply to your project:

if the attributes are defined in a superclass of the class you are creating, they won't show in the class namespace before calling `type.__new___`.

In other words:

```
class Base(metaclass=metaClass):
    FILE_PATH = "file.type"
    ADDRESS = "sadfsadfa"

class Sub(Base):
    pass
```

This code will fail your check - but would pass the check with `hasattr`, since it does the right thing when looking for attributes.

I think that this might be one of the few places where using `typing.cast` will not be just  a quick-and-dirty way to fool-up the static checker, but rather, the right thing to do: since the static checkr can't know what is the type returned by the call to `type.__new__`, we use  `typing.cast` to make it explicit.

As an extra thing to make it work, it MyPy has to know that instances of `metaClass` are supposed to have those attributes. The way I found to do that
is to annotate the wanted attributes into the metaclass itself.

Anyway, this passes `mypy --strict`

```
import typing as T

class metaClass(type):

    FILE_PATH: str
    ADDRESS: str

    def __new__(mcls, name: str, bases: tuple[type, ...], dct: dict[str, T.Any]) -> "metaClass":
        x = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, dct)

        if not hasattr(x, "FILE_PATH") or not hasattr(x, "ADDRESS"):
            raise NotImplementedError("FILE_PATH and ADDRESS not set")

        cls = T.cast(metaClass, x)
        #do stuff with x.FILE_PATH and x.ADDRESS
        a = cls.FILE_PATH
        return cls


class Base(metaclass=metaClass):
    FILE_PATH = "file.type"
    ADDRESS = "sadfsadfa"
```

(I did some renaming to avoid confusion - like subClass-> Base, since "subClass" is not a subclass of the metaclass, and the first parameter to `metaclass.__new__` to `mcls`: as it is the metaclass and it is easier to read if we reserve `cls` as a name for the class to be created)

---

One other option, since MyPY clearly can't figure out the metaclass mechanism, is to mark things inside the metaclass method to be ignored by MyPy with the  `# type: ignore` comment.  This `cast` however, seems to really be the right thing to do in this case.